# Effect of having "use strict"; in file scope, but not at the top

Tags: javascript

I understand it shouldn't be done, take this as an academic question.
If I was to, say, concatenate several JavaScript files, some with `'use strict';` at the top, and some without, what would be the outcome?

I know that if you put the phrase at the top of the file it enables strict mode for the entire file, and if it is at the start of a function it is scoped to that function.
But what if the first `'use strict';` is mid-way down? I guess you can extrapolate this quest to function-scoped uses as well.

Will it;

- have no effect,
- enable strict mode for the whole file, or
- somehow enable strict mode for only the remaining length of the code?

E.g.

```js
/*from file1.js*/
function bob() {
    willThisError = 'because of use strict mode below?';
}

/*from file2.js*/
"use strict";
function bob2() {
    var thisAuthor = 'likes to enable strict mode';
}
```

or

```js
//midway through function
function test() {
    willThisError = '?';
    'use strict';
    var orWillIt = 'have no effect';
}
```

I guess I could just test it myself, but I'm interested in a spec reference or something, and not to get caught up in browsers' individual interpretations on strict mode declaration.

Comment: It's just another expression statement.

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of concatenating `strict mode` scripts with non-strict mode scripts depends on the order in which you do it. If you start with a `strict` script, the whole script will look `strict`. If you start with a non-strict one, it'll look non-strict.

You can find a good reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode)

Comment: Ah yes, it does say `To invoke strict mode ... put the exact statement "use strict"; ... before any other statements`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode)

> Strict mode applies to entire scripts or to individual functions. It
>   doesn't apply to block statements enclosed in {} braces; attempting to
>   apply it to such contexts does nothing. eval code, Function code,
>   event handler attributes, strings passed to setTimeout, and the like
>   are entire scripts, and invoking strict mode in them works as
>   expected.

So I would take that to mean that at the top of the file or at the top of functions, or it does nothing.